What would it take for an AI to have beliefs?
This question is motivated by @Lowri's comment here:

And ChatGPT doesn't "rebut" anything. It just produces words. It doesn't believe those words. It doesn't think those words are true.

@keshlam expressed similar thoughts:

determining whether an AI understands the output it is producing you say huge question of its own and not able to be addressed in comments. For large language models such as chat GPT, this simple answer is that we understand how they operate, and there really is no opportunity for them to build semantic understanding; they are simply probabilistic text generators writ large.

However, both @Lowri and @keshlam would presumably grant that biological neural networks (or at the very least human ones, i.e., human brains) are capable of having beliefs. Presumably they would concede that humans can have beliefs because their brains can have beliefs.
So assuming that this is right, what exactly would it take (or what exactly is missing in current AIs) in order for an AI to be able to have beliefs?
Or is the premise of the question wrong and actually current AIs already display the ability to have beliefs?

See also: Does the success of AI (Large Language Models) support Wittgenstein's position that "meaning is use"?

Addressing duplicate charges - Can X have beliefs iff X is sentient/conscious?
This question is not a duplicate of At what point can a being be said to have gained sentience?. That question is asking about sentience/consciousness. My present question here is asking about beliefs. It's not obvious at all that conflating sentience/consciousness with beliefs is at all justified.
For instance, according to panpsychism, even electrons are conscious. Does it follow that electrons have beliefs?
Conversely, a philosophical zombie might arguably have beliefs, but by definition it is not conscious.
I'm open to being proven wrong but the conflation of the two seems false or at least unjustified to me.
See also:

Reddit/AskPhilosophy - Is consciousness a requirement for belief?
Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy - Belief


Relevant meta-discussion: How is a question about beliefs a duplicate of a question about sentience?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Think also about the following: if Susskind's complinentarity principle is true, then every black hole has a very good representation under its event horizon of the things outside the event horizon. In this sense, a black hole is a perfect model of the outside world, the better one the greater its mass, and has information compressed the best way possible (in equilibrium). It is a perfect quantum computer, running a simulation...

For starters, you’d have to demonstrate that they are conscious. In ordinary parlance, that is what a belief requires. Sure, you can re define belief to only mean representation, the same way you can re define words in general. But in that case, you should make the question more specific since that would obviously contradict what most people think of when they think of the word “belief”.

@Syed Where does consciousness/sentience appear as a requirement in the definition of belief here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/belief/?

@Syed See also: https://www.reddit.com/r/askphilosophy/comments/1dyte1i/is_consciousness_a_requirement_for_belief/

@user80226 key phrase: ordinary parlance. When most people talk about beliefs, we are almost always referring to the beliefs of biological humans or perhaps, at best, other highly intelligent animals. In contexts such as AI, it would then depend on what you mean by belief, but that is arguably a computer science question just as much as a philosophy one

@Syed "ordinary parlance" - That's too vague. Cite an official source that provides this definition.

@user80226 https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belief these definitions arguably all imply consciousness. Definitions are based on consensus though so this isn’t a point I want to harbor on in the first place, even if most people in the world perceive that word to involve conscious agents

I'm surprised to see so many considering this a duplicate of the question about sentience. Sentience and belief are related, sure, but surely different concepts that can be considered separately.

Lets hope they remain separate.

@JackAidley You're right. It shouldn't have been deleted as duplicate. But it should be deleted for other reasons, So I'm leaving it alone. == Capitalization screw ups due to speech typing

@Anixx If you're talking about (this paper)[https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9409089] By susskind, yes that's true, but what does it have to do with AI and Large language models?

I'm surprised to see so many people willing to consider that an inanimate object without any self awareness or cognitive ability is nonetheless somehow capable of holding a belief.

You ask:

What would it take for an AI to have beliefs?

According to the recently deceased Daniel Dennett, for AI to have beliefs, we need only attribute to it in an instrumentalist way the intentional stance:

Most abstract is the intentional stance, the domain of software and minds, which requires no knowledge of either structure or design,17 and "[clarifies] the logic of mentalistic explanations of behaviour, their predictive power, and their relation to other forms of explanation" (Bolton & Hill, 1996, p. 24). Predictions are made on the basis of explanations expressed in terms of meaningful mental states; and, given the task of predicting or explaining the behaviour of a specific agent (a person, animal, corporation, artifact, nation, etc.), it is implicitly assumed that the agent will always act on the basis of its beliefs and desires in order to get precisely what it wants... (emphasis mine)

In his book of the same title, what he says is that beliefs are not a real thing, that is, they have no material existence. A belief, rather, is part of an explanatory framework that we use to make sense of complex behavior. In fact, we can view AI through the intentional, design, and physical stances at will.
However, despite Dennett's claim, for many thinkers, it's an open question if it's possible for AI to have human-like beliefs and experience; on a broad reading of belief as a spontaneous intentional internal representation of the self or the world that requires no self-awareness, it is arguable they already do. But the vagueness of terms poses a challenge, and there are actually several related readings of this question:


Are AI systems capable of having belief? What exactly is belief?
Are AI systems capable of having representations? What exactly is a representation?
Are AI systems capable of replicating human belief? What does it mean to replicate human belief?


This sort of question is fraught with confusion, so immediately, the SEP offers us resources to suss out a response:

Belief (SEP)
Formal Representations of Belief (SEP)
Logic of Belief Revision (SEP)
Intentionality (SEP)

From the first SEP article:

Anglophone philosophers of mind generally use the term “belief” to refer to the attitude we have, roughly, whenever we take something to be the case or regard it as true. To believe something, in this sense, needn’t involve actively reflecting on it.

Computer systems are capable of having internal representations even about the external world and judging something to be true or false, and they needn't actively be aware or reflect on that process, so on the shallowest reading, yes, AI software can have belief. But this does not make it human belief, or even dog belief. (This, of course, is a generalization of the use of belief, whose necessary and sufficient conditions for many include it to be a property of sentient, biological beings unconditionally if one subscribes to prototypical definitions.) Belief and representation comes in many forms, and there is not valid reason to exclude non-biological electromechanical systems where biological systems are concerned as general principle.
Let us also acknowledge that mere belief is not knowledge if one accepts that judgment often plays some role in transforming belief to knowledge. Even with these resources, thinkers are going to have a strong set of opinions based on their personal definitions of 'belief', 'representation', 'thought', etc. Clearly, AI systems are not capable of belief and knowledge in the same way as people, period, because the richness of the complexity of the human brain in terms of using and understanding symbols is unmatched by even the most powerful computers such as Deep Blue, Watson, and so on. This is why modern computer science recognizes a distinction between the concepts of AI and AGI.
But systems are built that mimic human belief, desire, and intention, conveniently called Belief-Desire-Intention (BDI) software, and therefore, while software belief does not match the belief of humans, or arguably Great Apes generally, it might be on par with simpler organisms who are sometimes held to have cognition by ethologists. That is to say, a complicated software system that implements a formal representation of belief can produce robotic behavior that mimics the abilities of simple animals. Boston Dynamic's Spot is capable of generating a real-time representation of the world, generating a plan, and prioritizing and implementing action.
Combining robotic BDI, integrating natural language processing (NLP), and packaging it in a humanoid form not only can be done, but creates the effect called uncanny valley. These systems certainly do not fool anyone when time is taken to examine them, but they do reflect enough human-like properties to give pause, and certainly to form the foundation of philosophical discourse, which is arguably a form of experimental philosophy (SEP). Some thinkers faithfully imbue neurons with an elan vital or attribute quantum woo to consciousness, in a defense that somehow neurons are capable of leading to the emergent properties of consciousness in a way that transistors or not. But, personally, I've never seen a compelling argument, and functionalism (SEP), as flawed as it is, creates compelling lines of argument.
So, current systems arguably have beliefs, desires, and intentions if operationalization is the standard by which abstractions are deemed to exist. But they are shallow facsimiles of human forms of belief, desire, and intention in the same way even the most sophisticated human prosthetic hand resembles the biological human hand. And you'll observe strong knee-jerk reactions to the question in the same spirit of the uncanny valley. No! Computer can never think! Yes, computers are already self-aware! Some people react quite emotionally in the face of asserting that robots and computers can possess human-like qualities in the same way people will literally get angry if confronted about the their religious beliefs.
Ultimately, it would require a book-length work to provide a thorough response to differentiate how modern AI systems fall short of AGI, and thus human-level belief, desire, and intention. In fact, there are a lot of highly intelligent thinkers devoting energy to this issue now, and we see lines of debate that mimic the Searle/Dennett discourse surrounding minds, language, and consciousness. So it continues to be the job of philosophers, to wade through these conceptual questions.And continues to be the job of scientists and computer scientists to build bigger and more powerful formal systems of belief, desire, intention, and action. Who knows what quantum computers and other future technologies will bring.
See also:

Could general-AI language generation be a test for sentience, sapience, or consciousness? (PhilSE)
Why is it impossible for a program or AI to have semantic understanding? (PhilSE)
PhilPapers Survey 2020, Why do so many physicalists deny consciousness of future AI systems? (PhilSE)
Why are humans and AI often treated differently in cases where they perform nearly identical processes? (PhilSE)


But how can these beliefs be about something? How does an AI (or a human for that matter) pair internal representations to an external world? How does it (or the human) direct their belief to an external state of affairs either existent or fictional?

@Philomath lol Well, those are quite deep and complicated. On the simplest level, computers can reflect states of the world like video cameras can, right? And computers can pick out images in their video feed and designate them as objects, right? And computers can make decisions about those objects based on learning, right? And computers can use an ontology to formally reason about outcomes, right? These are all features of intentionally (SEP).

@Philomath My personal thoughts are that whatever makes a biological neural network able to represent and learn is present in artificial neural networks and other computational methods. There's not too much a difference is quality, but rather it's the quantity that separates modern AI from even the cognition of a chimp.

Modern AI systems already far outpaced the primitive animals in imitating behavior. They are close to successfully imitating humans and the only things they lack so far are the multimodality and motoric skills.

I am really intrigued by the problem of intentionality or aboutness. And you are right that if we understand how this works in biological neural networks then we can implement that in our artificial neural network. But to me it is still very unclear how a bunch of firing neurons can actually be about something in the outside world...

@Anixx Yet, they are just simulated networks that are basically matrix multiplications in Python (or whatever) on a Von Neumann architecture... Intriguing.

@Philomath I think a lot about this question, because I think it's promising on yielding insights. I would say, imagine if we have a switch that accepts inputs, and it makes one decision based on one set of inputs, and another otherwise, and imagine those inputs are generated by the shape of  polygon. Imagine it could tell the diff. between a tetrahedron and a sphere. If I make a mold of a sphere, can not that mold ultimately also be used to produce a sphere? Can I not also say then, the switch can be controlled not just by the sphere, but the mould utlimately? This is how I see it...

@Anixx I would suggest that what modern systems lack are the complexity, granularity, range, and throughput of biological systems, and the more systems rely on computational methods to self-replicate this the more human-like they become. In a word, modern AI lacks epigenesis.

@Philomath - How about this answer: Concrete beliefs are about whatever it is they are about (for an agent or class of agents) just like the tail of the spider-tailed horned viper is about (is interpreted by its victim, a poor lark still believing in metaphysical illusions as) a yummy spider. If we artificially cut "holding a belief" and almost all action (as is the case for non-robotic AI) attributing beliefs becomes rather superficial or empty. We need to start making more autonomous robots :)

@mudskipper Um, you think embodiment is necessary? Good point, because first of all the mind needs a sense of self and non-self to distinguish between internal and external states... Yeah, more robots. More is better.

@Philomath - A chat agent is also embodied (a little bit) - but it's actions are very limited and we tend to ignore the fact that it's us for whom its answers need to be or are supposed to be meaningful. Using them we imbue meaning to their actions. An autonomous robot, however, could damage itself by acting "stupidly" (misinterpreting things in its environment).

@mudskipper "A chat agent is also embodied (a little bit)" Thanks for recognizing that even software systems are to an extent embodied in that they rely on calls to the hardware in our conceptualization of their functionality. I think it's often a lost point that compilers may obfuscate systems-level functionality (I/O, thread management, register manipulation, etc.), but in terms of semantic action, the give and take from the hardware (again in our conceptual model), is a semantic action of a "body", so to speak.

Beliefs are for accomplishing goals, or avoiding harm. Until AIs are autonomous enough to self-direct and get desired things (and obviously, to get damaged or destroyed by the consequences of their actions) they won't learn, believe or be self-aware. Look at plants: no risk, no reward.

@ScottRowe AI is capable of everything you listed albeit in a different form. Machine learning is at the core image recognition, voice recognition, and semantic analysis.

Right, and we don't even have to punish them when they're wrong: it comes with the software!

We punish them in the most severe way possible: we kill them off and retrain a new model. So, we never give them a chance to become sentient. We need new kind of models that are continuously training, during their interactions. But we haven't quite figured out how to make those (plus trainability needs to decrease over time, just like language-learning is much more difficult for human adults than for small kids, otherwise there is too much plasticity and the adult cannot be teacher to the kid).

@mudskipper https://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/ This guy's all about continual learning systems. I've only read his work on semantic analysis,  though.

If we think programs can have beliefs
Look up belief in the dictionary and the most relevant definition will be something like "Mental acceptance of and conviction in the truth, actuality, or validity of something" (The American Heritage Dictionary) or "Conviction of the truth of anything" (Chamber's). ChatGPT is not sentient, it cannot have "mental acceptance" nor hold a "conviction" so under this definition it does not have beliefs but using definitions such as these for AI is unlikely to be productive because it immediately leads into the rabbit hole of trying to determine when, if ever, a machine becomes sentient and also leads to us having to ask whether the ability of a fly or a nematode to have beliefs depends on whether they are sentient or not.
Therefore I think it is more sensible to proceed by discarding the idea that a belief requires consciousness and thus adopting a broader meaning of the word belief. This does not reduce belief to mere state though, Excel does not believe that a cell contains the number 4 (say) and the words in this answer are not beliefs of Philosophy.SE's backend; rather beliefs need to be understandable as statements about the truth of some assertion.
Under this conception of what it means to have beliefs
Then ChatGPT, and other LLMs, do have beliefs
It's just that those beliefs are not related to our understanding of the "answer" they give to a "question".
It is common to talk about asking ChatGPT a question and getting an answer, but this is not actually what is happening. What ChatGPT is doing is taking your input and generating something that looks like something that might come after the words you typed in the dataset that it was trained on. Ever played the game where you reply with whatever sentence your phone's autocorrect suggests when you just keep accepting the top suggestion? That is closer to what ChatGPT is doing than what a person is doing when they answer a question.
It does not understand the question, it does not understand the answer, it is not even trying to do something that is related to understanding either the question or answer.
Instead what ChatGPT has beliefs about is how words relate to each other, about how the presence of words in its input window are related to words that should appear in its output window, and about what kind of orders words can appear in. ChatGPT believes that King is related to Queen in a way similar to how Man is related to Woman or Goose is to Gander. ChatGPT believes that 'an' comes before 'orrery' but that 'a' comes before 'dog'; and it believes these things with different, quantifiable levels of strength. And so on.

Right, but word frequency and order is such a trivial, flat world that calling any of it 'belief' is like saying a plant turns towards the window because it believes that the sun is that direction. My car will beep if I go out of the lane, and will put the brakes on if it believes that it's about to bump its nose on something. It could be wrong, but mostly its beliefs seem very sound, after years of my observations. I wish people did that well.

@ScottRowe: If all an LLM was doing was collecting trivial statistics on word order and frequency then, sure, but that's not what they're doing. Nor is your car's braking on "belief", rather it is a simple algorithm checking whether speed, direction and distance lead to a collision within a predetermined threshold.

Simple, except for that little binocular vision part. It took a billion years for animals to evolve that. Yeah, I was using 'belief' in jest.

In general, when talking about "AI", this cannot be answered now, no more than a question like "how do we know aliens from outer space have what we call 'belief'". If and when AIs (in the sense of AGI - artificial general intelligences) come around, we can try the question again. But right now there is not a hint of anybody even having an idea how a real AGI – something which would be considered an entity in itself – would work.
What can deftly be answered is that what we consider AI colloquially today – specifically, GenAI or GPTs or LLMs – can absolutely not have anything related to belief.
This follows directly from how these programs work. Yes, when taken as a black box they simulate or reproduce some aspects of intelligence very successfully. But internally there simply is nothing there which could even remotely be considered an entity that would be capable of having attributes like being capable belief.
Yes, they are incredibly complex; yes, they are black boxes internally; yes, there are some emergent capabilities of them which are hard to explain. But what is not hard is to understand how they work. They are – relatively speaking – simple programs that work on humongous amounts of data structured in a way that is not approachable to full human understanding anymore. But although we are not capable of groking the huge amount of data ourselves anymore, we can absolutely still understand just fine how they work. The lights are most definitely not on.
This does not mean that current GenAIs are not absolutely fascinating programs and have been and will be continually changing our society more than most other developments in the past decades. It it is still true that the astounding capabilities they have now will only ever become better, not worse. It could absolutely be that – especially as their agent capabilities are increased – we or our children will live with a GenAI partner from birth to death and not be able to distinguish that from a human partner. I find it very likely that we will program them to become ever more indistinguishable from humans, and will increasingly make humans feel like the GenAIs are real entities. There are huge amounts of money to be made here, and this development is already happily on its way (for example in the market of virtual friends, often with barely hidden or all-out emotional/sexual connotations).
But as long as we are talking about GenAI based on GPTs and LLMs we are not talking about entities that would be attributed concepts like beliefs, consciousness, the "what is it like to be..." question, and so on and forth.
Oh and to answer your question, "what would it take for an AI to have beliefs": the AI would have to be based on a mechanism that somehow invites the thought that this could be the case, and not only a relatively trivial word generator. Right now, nobody knows how that could look like, hence the question right now is hardly answerable in a sensible way.

Children are said to have mastered language use when they can lie convincingly, that is: they know what the other person knows and does not know, so they can fabricate a plausible scenario. This happens around age 4 or 5. The child can model another human's state of belief about a situation, model their own, and then model a new state of affairs that is also believable to the other person and gets the child what they want. We could call this The Churling Test. When AI can pull this off... Well, it will be too late by then. You think we have "fake news" and "alternative facts" now...

First question we should pose is "what is a belief?" I suggest the following definition: "having belief is having certain statement true in the internal model of the world".
Is so, the AIs definitely can have beliefs as long as they have an internal representation of the external world.

Do you think the multi-dimensional vector space of an LLM is an internal representation of the external world? In other words, do you really think that ChatGTP believes what it writes?

@Philomath absolutely not always it believes what it writes, but that it has an internal representation is quite universally agreed. What it writes is not always what is true in the internal representation as it can be prompted or trained to lie.

Do you think Wikipedia has an internal representation of the external world?

@Philomath If we take Wikipedia pages without users, possibly, not as the pages are too loosely connected compared to external world, which is not enough for a fully-fledged functioning model. But if we take it together with users (even if those users have no information from the external world other than from Wikipedia), then probably, yes, as the users create interconnections between the pages that in some sense imitate or model or reflect similar connections between events and objects in the real world. For instance, a change in one page leads to a corresponding change in another one.

@Philomath a model should not only have data, but also laws, interconnecting this data in a way, resembling the external world...

This seems to just reformulate the problem, not address it. To "have a belief about the world" or to "have an internal representation of the external world" is largely just a different way of naming the same things.

It's a new "Chinese Room" scenario: a kid with Wikipedia becomes the smartest guy on earth!

If it quacks like a duck....
How do we know that other humans have beliefs? We have conversations with them and they convince us of the existence of these beliefs.
It's possible to have a conversation with some AIs now, and I think some have passed the Turing Test. If any of these AIs are able to convince the testers that they have beliefs, why shouldn't we consider this to be true?
Some people have formed "relationships" with chatbots. They think the bot has feelings for them, so they would presumably consider these to be beliefs.
Of course, it's not hard to get an AI to express contradictory beliefs. AIs don't always respond consistently, and generative AIs frequently produce "hallucinations" because they're just regurgitating words based on statistical models, not based on higher-level representations of knowledge.
But it's also possible to confuse people and get them to say things they don't really mean, and even contradict themselves. Would we say they don't actually believe what they're saying?
To some extent, I think one of the reasons we make qualitative distinctions between the way humans and AIs act is that we know what's going on under the covers of AI (since we designed them), while human mental activity is still very mysterious. AI can mimic some of the behaviors of humans, but they can't reach our rich complexity yet. But as with comparisons with other animals, this may just be a question of degree, not kind.
When a chatbot qualifies an answer with "I am merely a large language model....", we know that this has likely been hard-coded into the application. Does that mean it's not a belief? Humans often produce rote answers, like "I can neither confirm nor deny...", does that mean they're also mere automatons?

I am not aware of any AI that has passed the turing test under any reasonable definition of the test. If you have a citation, I would be very interested. Also, you touch on this, but I think you are giving short shrift to the fact that chatGPT and similar systems have no consistency at all to their "beliefs" which is normally an expected attribute of beliefs as the term is usually used. Yes, beliefs can and do change over time (mine have), but there is usually some adjustment needed. ChatGPT will often give radically different answers if you simply ask it to regenerate a response...

I did a google search, some sites said that it has been passed, others said no.

GPT-4 has passed the Turing test, researchers claim

Wikipedia: "Thirty-three percent of the event judges thought that Goostman was human; the event organiser Kevin Warwick considered it to have passed Turing's test."

Gosh. People thought Eliza was convincing, 60 years ago. I don't trust humans to decide this one. Put the AIs in a gladiator ring and let them prove themselves. (Then, destroy the winner)

@ScottRowe (At risk of sounding silly giving a serious answer to a joke) isn't that kind of the point of the Turing Test (and my answer)? There's no objective way to judge whether an entity has intelligence, beliefs, understanding, etc., just subjective judgement by humans who recognize it in each other.

Up voting this for consistency with my belief that sentience is a matter of degree rather than kind, although I would still put current AI systems so low on that scale that I think colloquially granting this would be horribly misleading. Idiot - savant worm, perhaps, and that may be giving it too much credit.

@keshlam I think it's better than a worm, since they don't even give an illusion of sentience. And even when an AI is totally wrong, what it says usually makes sense and is related to the prompt. ChatGPT may be more reliable a source than Trump, but that's damning with faint praise.

A worm seeks to satisfy its needs, and has some non-trivial behaviors to achieve that. If you prefer, you can substitute fruit fly; they are a standard animal model for simple neurology. My opinion is that the llm appears to make more sense only because its behavior is it in a space that we recognize as normally belonging to higher intelligence, but the way it does so is via a relatively simple. I grant that this is a matter of perceptions, definitions, and interpretations.

@keshlam Good point. It's very easy for humans to discount the cleverness exhibited by almost all forms of life because we elevate the importance of actions that seem to be uniquely human. We're also frequently being surprised by how non-unique those are (we keep finding more animals that use tools). Language is still something that seems to set us apart, so anything that seems to mimic that well will be viewed highly.

There are “beliefs” and “justified beliefs”. A detective could trust every suspect he interviews to tell the truths and call what he learns “his beliefs”. The problem is that he would never catch any criminal because these beliefs have nothing to do with reality.
Now look at chatGPT. It is known that it just analyses data and forms sentences that seem to agree with its data. It doesn’t have “beliefs” but “beliefs” wouldnt fix it’s fundamental problem that it often draws bad conclusions from input data, and apparently when it is asked for true statements it creates statements that somehow match its data but are completely made up. It has been known to make up cases of sexual harassment that looked similar to real cases but were completely made up, and court cases that looked similar to real ones but were equally made up.
So whether it had beliefs or not made no practical difference. You wouldn’t accept the beliefs of a fantasist, or the beliefs of some moron who believes everything he is told.
If ChatGPT had justified beliefs based on critical examination of its data, then it would be a small step to tell stories with the intent to convince you of things it wants you to believe. That is intentionally lying.

I would accept that the credulous moron believes what they are saying, if they are able to do significantly more with it then parrot back fragments of it.

If we're willing to say that something can have beliefs without sentience, why not take that idea the whole way? Why not ask whether bricks or muffins can have beliefs? What makes AI special that we feel we can ask this question about it?
I'd say nothing in particular, especially if we're  specifying non-sentience in our framing.

Bricks lack intentionality known as aboutness. A computer can form and modify representations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intentionality?wprov=sfla1

@JD A computer can form and modify representations, maybe. But does that mean it has a mental state that can be described as intentionality? Does a computer have a mind?

That depends on one's definition of mind, right?

@JD I disagree with your notion that AI can manifest intentionality, because intentionality is a mental state as your own link points out; we can't observe mental states. We can possibly infer mental states from outward behaviour, but must recognize the limitations of such an approach. The same goes for intention and rationality. As for goal directed behaviour; rocks rolling down a hill exhibit something rather similar, I'm afraid.

I'm also unsure how I've moved any goalposts here. If you can explain more, I'd be happy to correct myself or otherwise clarify.

When AI starts moving the goalposts, we'll know we have something. It's the Connie Test!

ROFL, thanks @ScottRowe heh heh.

Intentionality is about reprsentations and not mental states, and you dodge the point.  Then, you claim computers have no mental states, but then you concede they can't be observed but must be inferred. This is after claiming computers and bricks are fundamentally alike. I would suggest that your inferences about mental states might suffer from a lack of knowledge about the parallels between neural and non-neural computational systems.  If biological neural networks have intentionally,  you'd have to explain why artificial neural networks don't.  Hiding behind the woo of 'mind' is a dodge.

But Im not interested in an extended discusion.

@JD I'll reply for the benefit of anyone else who's reading. The link you provided on intentionality describes it as a mental state in the first line. I didn't claim that computers don't have mental states, though I certainly express doubt. Nor did I claim computers and bricks are fundamentally alike. I doubt my lack of knowledge about said parallels affect my judgement, as I'm a published author in the field of neural networks and am fully aware of neuromorphism.

For anyone reading; I'd say that if you want to argue that computers have minds because their code or hardware is neuromorphic, your first challenge is to prove that humans have minds; that they are experiencing the same/a similar thing as you and are not p-zombies. If you are successful in this endeavour, I'll be the first to toast your Nobel Prize.

Excellent rebuttal, and we'll leave it at that as proving humans have minds serious misapprehends the nature of the mind. Agree to disagree.

@JD Ride safe man :) Nice talking, God bless!


What would it take for an AI to have beliefs?

I can't answer this question without providing a definition of belief:

A belief is an beings conviction that something is true, or their feeling of certainty that something exists or is good.

At the current stage of AI, any "truth" is a product of developer programming or simply a reflection of our own beliefs.
The extent to which AI will have "beliefs" is proportional to the ability of AI to alter its own programming.

AI's aren't conscious so they don't think and so do not have beliefs. They have been accurately described as stochastic parrots, or to use the technical term, large language models. They merely imitate human thinking without there actually being any thinking involved. They stochastically predict the next word, sentence and paragraph.

LLMs explicitly do not imitate human thinking. They are stochastic text generators written large with some biasing features to set their initial state. They imitate human text patterns, specifically the large samples that they have been given.

@keshlam: What are you stating that I haven't said in my post? I said that they "stochastically predict the next word, sentence & paragraph". How is this different from your critique? And I also explicitly state that they are technically called "large language models". So what exactly is your critique?

I am quibbling with "imitate human thinking without there being any thinking involved." I understand that we're saying the same thing, I just don't like that phrasing since I think it is likely to reinforce some kinds of confusion. But that's purely personal; feel free to ignore me.
